# expansion with escape character

Tags: bash, shell, escape-characters

I am having trouble doing expansion with this because of the escape character.

`UNF\1122`

Right now I am trying to stick with the really simple example of:

`ps -ef | grep $USER`

Eventually after I deal with the escape character I would like to do this.

`ipcs -m | grep $USER | awk '{printf "%s ",$2}'`

I know `$USER` has a value because I did this.

`$ echo $USER
UNF\1122`

Please don't ask me why the administrator decided to put a `\` in the username because I don't know.

To solve this I tried single quotes and double quotes. I have also tried to change username like this.

`USER="UNF\\\\1122" and USER='UNF\\1122'`

Comment: Quote the variable and try `grep -F "$USER"` to match it as a fixed string not a regex. [Reasons to always quote shell variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, as depending on the utility a `\1` may have meaning, for example a back reference in `grep`, but not so in `getent`. Shell interpolation also complicates matters.

```
# getent sees a\\b, cannot find this literal string
$ getent passwd 'a\\b'

# let the shell interpolate \\ to \ so getent sees a\b
$ getent passwd a\\b
a\b:x:9999:9999:Slash Gordon:/:/bin/sh

# or no iterpolation, literal a\b passed to getent
$ getent passwd 'a\b'
a\b:x:9999:9999:Slash Gordon:/:/bin/sh

# oops, shell interpolated \\ to \ and thus grep sees \b metacharacter
$ grep "a\\b" /etc/passwd
vcsa:x:69:69:virtual console memory owner:/dev:/sbin/nologin
a\b:x:9999:9999:Slash Gordon:/:/bin/sh

# oops, also shell interpolation, so grep sees a\b metachar
$ grep a\\b /etc/passwd
vcsa:x:69:69:virtual console memory owner:/dev:/sbin/nologin
a\b:x:9999:9999:Slash Gordon:/:/bin/sh

# no interpolation, pass \\ to grep, which then treats as literal \
$ grep 'a\\b' /etc/passwd
a\b:x:9999:9999:Slash Gordon:/:/bin/sh
$
```